# There are no local edits to upload in ArcGIS Collector?

Tags: arcgis-collector, ipad

I edited a feature layer offline. I made sure that the Sync and Edit options were selected before I exported the service (and verified on ArcGIS online). I had no problems collecting the data, and could see there were 19 features that were not synced. When I tried to export it said "Push-only sync is enabled and there are no local edits to upload". I can see the local edits, and yes, push-only is enabled, but I am the only individual editing the layer so it doesn't matter. So why aren't the local edits being synced?

I am using an iPad Pro. I have a Bad Elf receiver linked to the iPad. I've used this system before, and am unsure what I did wrong!

Comment: Perhaps try to sync later. Sometimes agol health board is not completely honest, to say the least. Happend few times to me...

Comment: Not sure, but if its anything like the desktop software, perhaps the edits you made had not been saved to the local device yet?